# Nested form not posting to both tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

My Ruby on Rails 4 form creates a question. I want to also add the ability to create 4 answers to the question. It is creating the question but no answers. It is not posting to the answers table, only the questions table.

How do you get it to post to the answers to the answers table?

My log POST:

```
Started POST "/questions" for x at 2014-04-17 13:16:21 -0700
Processing by QuestionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x", "question"=>{"content"=>"Test question 2", "question_type"=>"MC", "category"=>"i
p_voice", "product_id"=>"1", "active"=>"0", "answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"one piggy", "correct"=>"1", "question_id"=>""}, "1"=>{"content"=>"two elephants", "correct"=>
"0", "question_id"=>""}, "2"=>{"content"=>"one lion", "correct"=>"0", "question_id"=>""}, "3"=>{"content"=>"six oranges", "correct"=>"0", "question_id"=>""}}}, "commit"=>"Create 
Question"}
Unpermitted parameters: answers_attributes
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "questions" ("active", "category", "content", "created_at", "product_id", "question_type", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["active", fals
e], ["category", "ip_voice"], ["content", "Test question 2"], ["created_at", Thu, 17 Apr 2014 20:16:21 UTC +00:00], ["product_id", 1], ["question_type", "MC"], ["updated_at", Thu
, 17 Apr 2014 20:16:21 UTC +00:00]]
(31.5ms)  commit transaction
```

My questions_controller

```
def new
@question = Question.new
4.times { @question.answers.build }

@products = Product.all
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_question
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:content, :question_type, :category, :product_id, :active)
end

# Before filters
def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
end
```

My answers_controller

```
def new
@answer = Answer.new
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_answer
  @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def answer_params
  params.require(:answer).permit(:content, :question_id, :correct)
end

# Before filters
def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
end
```

My question.rb model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:contecnt].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

My answer.rb model

```
belongs_to :question
```

My Form!

```
<h1>New question</h1>
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_questions' %>
<%= render 'form', f: f %>
<h1>Answers</h1>
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
<%= render 'four_answers', :f => builder %>
<% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Create Question", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is always getting rejected with the `reject_if` option.  Your `a[:contectnt].blank?` is always true because the key `contectnt` does not exist in the hash.

Use `:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }` as follows:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

**Update** and I suppose the accurate answer!:

As the log shows you are not permitting `answers_attributes` through mass assignment, you also need to add `answers_attributes` to the `permit` list as follows:

```
# app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:question_type, :category, :product_id, :active, answers_attributes: [ :content, :correct, :question_Id ] )
end
```

Please see [Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) at edgeapi for further details.

Comment: Have you double checked strong params?  I didn't notice this `Unpermitted parameters: answers_attributes` in your log before.  The issue is in your controller, and has to do with strong parameters!

Comment: Okay, I have all the attributes in params.require(:x).permit(:attributes...) Do I need something else?

Comment: @DDDD, please, update your question with the controller code you have if you need further help.

Comment: @DDDD, in that case: please see [`Strong Parameters`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html), which Rails 4 replaces the old "attr_accessible" declaration in the model by moving it to the controller.